# How can I define member function as Thrift service?

Tags: c++, c++11, rpc, thrift

I want to use RPC to call the member function of a class object.

For example:

```
class A {
 public:
  int foo(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
};
```

The client want to call A::foo remotely, in this case how to define the thrift file? Since go rpc can do this easily, I wonder how to do it in C++ with thrift.

---

My solution to do that is a little bit tricky:

Define raw function type in thrift file as below, it seems like a wrapper of member function `A::foo`:

```
service XXX {
  i64 div(1:i64 a, 2:i64 b)
}
```

In server code:

```
class XXXhandler : XXXIf {
 public:
  int div(int a, int b) {
    return obj.foo(a, b);
  }
 private:
  A obj;
};
```

Is there any simple way to do that in thrift?

Comment: So you want the server to create an `A` when asked for some service, then invoke a method `foo` on it when they get a request?  Can you change `A` or is it beyond your ken? (Ie, make it a service itself)  You wrote 1 line to expose `A`, 1 line to expose `A::foo`, one line to implement the exposed `A`, 1 line to allocate `A` in the exposed serive, and 1 line to forward the method.  Barring reflection, how much simpler is it going to get?

Comment: @Yakk it is just a simple example, all I want to do is to call member function of server end in client end.

Comment: yes, that is a repeat of what I said.  A `server` is an object type/instance, a function is a method, and your code aligns the C++ with the thrift interface.  Again, what do imagine would be "simpler"?

Comment: I guess I just misread the question. Yakk is right, it will not become much simpler.